# Eloquent ORM ManytoMany erro de constraint 1452

Tags: laravel-eloquent, orm

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando o Eloquent ORM, porem estou com problema com a relação N pra N,

O relacionamento é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os registro que estou utilizando como teste na tabela ProdutoGrupos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os registro que estou utilizando como teste na tabela ProdutoSubGrupos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como vocês podem ver a tabela Pivot é a produtogrupos_produtosubgrupos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As models estão assim:

```
class Grupos extends Model{
    protected $table = 'produtosgrupos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'gruposId';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'gruposId',
        'grupos_titulo',
        'grupos_slug',
    ];

    public function subgrupos() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(SubGrupos::Class, 'produtosgrupos_produtossubgrupos', 'gruposId', 'gruposId');
    }
}
```

Estou tentando criar a realção na tabela pivot dessa forma:

```
$modelGrupo = new Grupos;
$grupo = $modelGrupo->find(3);
$grupo->subgrupos()->attach(14); //o erro de constraint aconetece aqui
```

Fiz um teste diretamente no banco de dados e funcionou:

```
INSERT INTO produtosgrupos_produtossubgrupos (gruposId, subgruposId) VALUES (3, 14);
```

e execultou normalmente, eu esqueci alguma coisa no eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está a passar incorrectamente o quarto argumento ( foreign key)
Está gruposId onde deveria estar subgruposId

```
 public function subgrupos() {
       return $this->belongsToMany(SubGrupos::Class, 'produtosgrupos_produtossubgrupos', 'gruposId', 'subgruposId');
    }
```

Comment: precisamente jorge! obrigado!